# Autolayout UILabel multiline strange top padding

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel, autolayout

Autolayout situation

Red view - Holder view, which is centered horizontaly and has max witdh

Label 1 has just the left, top, right distance set to 0

Label 2 has just the left, right distance set to 0 and top to Label 1 to 4px

**All works fine, when the Label 1 is single line, as soon as there is another line a strange top padding occures**

[image]

Comment: It's probably because font size is changing and the text gets centred. If you want to show multiline text, you should change the frame size (height) instead of changing the font.

Comment: thats the minscale property of the UILabel, as it is set automatically

Comment: Exactly. The padding probably happens due to minscale.

Comment: allright, but is this a bug on apple side? what can be done so that the fitting is calculated correctly, with the minscale?

Comment: Do you intent to leave that red-ish color as background?

Comment: nope, thats just to show the artificial padding

Comment: So do you think your users will think about / be bothered by the artificial padding?

Comment: thats not the matter, it needs to work right :)

Comment: "right" is a very broad word. The artificial padding is probably added to display the text in a way Apple thinks it's "right".